# Is there a way to access all the variables in workspace sequentially?

Tags: matlab

I would like to remove the first elements of all the variables (vectors of the same size) in my Matlab working space. Is there a way to do it without type variable names one by one?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to use dynamic variable names; don't. If all your variables are (semi-)similar, use (cell-)arrays and cut the first value out of those.

Comment: If you ever want to do the same thing to bunch of variables, that's a really good indication that they should be grouped into an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`evalin`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html) and [**`who`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/who.html):

```
x = 42;
y = 1984;

allVars = who;
for ii = 1:numel(allVars)
    temp = evalin('base',allVars{ii});

    %// do whatever needs to be done
    disp(temp)
end
```

But you should rethink your whole code if you need to do stuff that way... Consider using [**structs**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) or
[**cell arrays**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html).

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments and other answers, if you have to do that it is a sign that your code is badly organised. Follow *thewaywewalk* advices and links to learn how to use `struct` and `cell` arrays. It will make your life much easier, and you won't have to use the highly non-recommended `eval` family of function.

Now if you still need to do it, here's one way:

I start by creating a few variables of different type:

```
a = rand(20,1) ;
b=a*5
c = rand(32,4) ;
d = 'toto'
e = {'yop'}
```

So now my workspace looks like:
[image: vlist1]

```
%%
vlist = whos ; %// get the list of workspace variable and their type
nVar = numel(vlist) ;

%% // remove non "double" entries (change type as you need)
type2keep = 'double' ;
idx2drop = false(nVar,1) ;
for k=1:nVar
    idx2drop(k) = ~strcmp( vlist(k).class , type2keep ) ;
end
vlist(idx2drop) = [] ; %// drop variables which are not 'double'

%% // Now check the sizes
size2keep = [20 1] ;                                            %// size of target variables
vsize = reshape( [vlist.size] , 2 , [] ).' ;                    %'// get an array of the variable sizes
idxok = vsize(:,1)==size2keep(1) & vsize(:,2)==size2keep(2) ;   %// find variables that match
vlist = vlist(idxok) ;                                          %// keep only matching variable in the list

%% // now remove the first elements
nElem2remove = 3 ; %// number of elements to remove
nVar = numel(vlist) ;

for k=1:nVar
    string2evaluate = sprintf('%s(1:%d)=[]',vlist(k).name,nElem2remove) ; %// will produce on 1st line: a(1:3)=[]
    eval( string2evaluate )
end
```

yep, it worked, I removed the 3 first elements of all variables of type `double` which had size `[20 1]`. Their new size is now `[17 1]`:

[image: vlist2]